# Is there any posible to create external load balancer for pod in cluster created by kubeadm tool

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have created python web-server and created docker image for that. Secondly I created Kubernetes cluster with kubeadm and created a service with type load balancer but I got External IP in Pending state so I came to know that External Load balancer can not be created in kubeadm tool.
So my task is to create pod replica of web-server and access through Pubic IP and the request should be load balanced between pod.
Can someone help me for this ?

Comment: tell me more about your environment? public cloud or bare metal on Prem?

Comment: It's public cloud

Comment: can you please say which public cloud?

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi I'm using AWS

Comment: have you setup aws cloud provider? https://blog.scottlowe.org/2018/09/28/setting-up-the-kubernetes-aws-cloud-provider/

Comment: I have a doubt so as I said I created cluster with kubeadm so should I configure cloud provider? can you please explain I'm new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options in your scenario an choosing between them is up to you based in your needs.

The fact it's pending forever is expected behavior.

By default, the solution proposed by Kubeadm requires you to [define a cloud-provider](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) to be able to use resources like [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#aws) offered by your Cloud Provider.

Another option is to use a out-of-box solutions as [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

MetalLB isn't going to allocate an External IP for you, it will allocate a internal IP inside our VPC and you have to create the necessary routing rules to route traffic to this IP.

Comment: Okay Thank you so much.